# How to get verbose information from `zfs get`

Tags: network-share, zfs, nfs4

Running Ubuntu 14...

```
"14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
```

...with Ubuntu zfs...

```
libzfs2/trusty,now 0.6.5.11-1~trusty amd64 [installed,automatic]
mountall/trusty,now 2.53-zfs1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.53-zfs1]
ubuntu-zfs/trusty,now 8~trusty amd64 [installed]
zfs-dkms/trusty,now 0.6.5.11-1~trusty amd64 [installed]
zfs-doc/trusty,now 0.6.5.11-1~trusty amd64 [installed,automatic]
zfsutils/trusty,now 0.6.5.11-1~trusty amd64 [installed]
```

I've set the NFS share using ...

```
zfs set sharenfs="rw=@1xx.xxx.xxx.0/255.255.254.0,rw=@10.0.0.0/24" zpool/datashare
```

...but when I query I only get `ON/OFF` reporting...

```
root# zfs get  sharenfs zpool/datashare
NAME             PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
zpool/datashare  sharenfs  off       local

root# zfs get  sharesmb zpool/datashare
NAME             PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
zpool/datashare  sharesmb  on        local
```

**Is there any way to get a full reporting of the `sharenfs` options?**

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Oracle docs for ZFS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1448/gayne.html#glivq):

> As in the previous releases, you display the value of the `sharenfs`
>   property by using `zfs get sharenfs` property or by using the `zfs get all` command syntax.
>
> `# zfs get sharenfs rpool/fs1
>   NAME       PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
>   rpool/fs1  sharenfs  on        local`
>
> The new `share` information is available by using the `zfs get share`
>   command.
>
> `# zfs get share rpool/fs1
>   NAME       PROPERTY  VALUE  SOURCE
>   rpool/fs1  share     name=rpool_fs1,path=/rpool/fs1,prot=nfs  local`
>
> The new `share` information is not available in the `zfs get all` command
>   syntax.

Try this:

```
# zfs get share zpool/datashare
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that lists all the properties for the datastore, but not the details of any individual property. I.e. It tells me that `sharenfs` is indeed `YES` but does not tell me that it was shared with certain IP addresses allowed (like `zfs set sharenfs="rw=@xxx.xxx.xxx.200/255.255.255.255" zpool/datashare`). I can deduce some information about what was used with the `set sharenfs` command from the `exportfs` output - but there's a lot of options that can be put in during the set, that aren't displayed there.